# Bootstrap nave bar from json data giving some different result

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I am creating a bootstrap navebar from json data and i have done it almost .
i am facing issue at one place only

```js
var data = {
        "India": [
                {
                  "type": "delhi",
                  "link": "https: //www.google.com"
                },
                {
                  "type": "mumbai",
                  "link": "https: //www.google.com"
                }
              ],
              "australia": [
                {
                  "type": "sydney",
                  "link": "https: //www.google.com"
                },
                {
                  "type": "melbourn",
                  "link": "https: //www.google.com"
                }
              ],
              "spain": [
                {
                  "type": "valencia",
                  "link": "https: //www.google.com"
                },
                {
                  "type": "madrid",
                  "link": "https: //www.google.com"
                }
              ],
              "logout": [
                {
                    "type": "",
                  "link": "Logout servlet"
                }
              ]
            }

$(document).ready(function() {
 
 for (var item in data) { 
     var _menu = "";
        var _submenuData = data[item];
        if(_submenuData.length > 0) {
         var _submenu = "";
            
         for(var i = 0; i < _submenuData.length; i++) {
             _submenu += "<a class='dropdown-item' href='" + _submenuData[i]["link"] + "'>" + _submenuData[i]["type"] + "</a>";
        }
        
        _menu = "<li class='nav-item dropdown'>"
          + "<a class='nav-link dropdown-toggle' href='' id='navbardrop' data-toggle='dropdown'> " + item + " </a>"
                + "<div id='drop' class='dropdown-menu'>"
                + _submenu
    + "</div>"
                + "</li>";
        }
        else {
         _menu = "<li class='nav-item'>"
          + "<a class='nav-link' href=''> " + item + " </a>"
                + "</li>";    //here at href i want to use the link i am getting in json
        }
        
        $("#navbarId").append(_menu);
    }

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet"
 href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script
 src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script
 src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
 <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
  data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
  aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false"
  aria-label="Toggle navigation">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
 </button>
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
  <ul id="navbarId" class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
  </ul>
 </div>
 </nav>
```

for Logout i am getting type=""  and link:"LogoutServlet"  i dont want to show it on dropdown i only want it to be menu and on clicking on that it should follow the link.
i want Logout to only be the menu

can anyone out there help me out

Answer (score 0):

Each object array contains 2 elements, except for the logout array, which only contains one. So change the `if` statement in your JavaScript to reflect that.

`if(_submenuData.length > 1) {`

*Edit:*

Added `_submenuData[0].link` inside `else ... href`:

---

```js
var data = {
    "India": [
        {
            "type": "delhi",
            "link": "https: //www.google.com"
        },
        {
            "type": "mumbai",
            "link": "https: //www.google.com"
        }
    ],
    "australia": [
        {
            "type": "sydney",
            "link": "https: //www.google.com"
        },
        {
            "type": "melbourn",
            "link": "https: //www.google.com"
        }
    ],
    "spain": [
        {
            "type": "valencia",
            "link": "https: //www.google.com"
        },
        {
            "type": "madrid",
            "link": "https: //www.google.com"
        }
    ],
    "logout": [
        {
            "type": "",
            "link": "Logout servlet"
        }
    ]
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    for (var item in data) {
        var _menu = "";
        var _submenuData = data[item];
        if(_submenuData.length > 1) {
            var _submenu = "";

            for(var i = 0; i < _submenuData.length; i++) {
                _submenu += "<a class='dropdown-item' href='" + _submenuData[i]["link"] + "'>" + _submenuData[i]["type"] + "</a>";
            }

            _menu = "<li class='nav-item dropdown'>"
                + "<a class='nav-link dropdown-toggle' href='' id='navbardrop' data-toggle='dropdown'> " + item + " </a>"
                + "<div id='drop' class='dropdown-menu'>"
                + _submenu
                + "</div>"
                + "</li>";
        }
        else {
            _menu = "<li class='nav-item'>"
                + "<a class='nav-link' href='"+ _submenuData[0].link +"'> " + item + " </a>"
                + "</li>";
        }

        $("#navbarId").append(_menu);
    }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script
 src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script
 src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
 <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
         data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
         aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false"
         aria-label="Toggle navigation">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
 </button>
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
  <ul id="navbarId" class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
  </ul>
 </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: yup right approach..but i have an another question look i have removed the href linked to logout which i was giving hardcoded..now i want to use the link which i am getting in json for the Logout